# Is it safe to launch an activity from a non-ui thread?

Tags: android

Suppose my activity ui-thread spawns a separate thread at some point. Is it safe for that new thread to fire off an Intent for launching a new activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I could be wrong, but I think `startActivity()` internally executes in the UI thread. So yes, it should be safe.

If you wanted to be 100% sure, invoke your `startActivity()` in your activity's `runOnUiThread()` as a `Runnable`.

Comment: I checked the source code for `startActivity()` and yes it does run on the main thread so your safe to call it from the background.

Comment: It not in all firmwares/cases. I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` after call `startActivityForResult`. You need run this in UI thread or in some bad implementation you can get some crashes.

Comment: It is not safe to call startActivity() from a background thread.

Answer (score 10):

The first few lines of `startActivityForResult()` (used by all the `startActivity()` variants) suggests that it is ok:

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
            mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
                this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
                intent, requestCode, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an experiment:
 - started activity from non ui thread and in onCreate() put a cycle from 1 to 100 where i were printing thread name Thread.currentThread()
 - put the same cycle right after activity start in non ui thread

Output was simultaneously showing they names Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main] and Thread[main,5,main]