# startactivity() not working from inner class that extends ListActivity

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-listview

Title basically says it all.  The below code doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't start the new activity.  Code below.

I have tried modifying `startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, NewActivity.class));` to read `startActivity(new Intent(MyListActivity.this, NewActivity.class));`

I have been testing this in Eclipse with an AVD.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated - thanks!

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

private Context mCtx;
MyContentObserver mContentObserver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(onSavedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.calls_list);

    mContentObserver = new MyContentObserver(this);

    this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, mContentObserver);

}

private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private Context mCtx;
    public MyContentObserver(Context ctx ) {
        super(null);
        mCtx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, NewActivity.class));
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: What I am noticing is that I cannot launch anything from inside the `ContentObserver`.  I tried using `sendbroadcast` as well with no luck.

Comment: I ended up moving my `ContentObserver` to a `Service`.  I was able to use `sendBroadcast` from there

Answer (score 3):

### Possible cause 1

The activity has not been declared.

You have to add the activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

You should add this to your `<application>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="package.name.NewActivity">
    <!-- Add an intent filter here if you wish -->
</activity>
```

### Possible cause 2

The `onChange` method doesn't actually run.

Please use the code below to verify that the onChange method actually gets called:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    MyContentObserver mContentObserver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(onSavedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.calls_list);

        mContentObserver = new MyContentObserver();

        this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, mContentObserver);
    }

    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.d("MyListActivity.MyContentObserver", "onChange");
            startActivity(new Intent(MyListActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
        }
    }   
}
```

You could also try launching the activity from `onCreate` to make sure it can be launched.

Comment: with a line like this? `<activity android:name=".NewActivity" />` ?

Comment: Yes, check your logcat, if this is the reason there will be a line saying the activity could not be found

Comment: Here is how my `<activity>` tag currently reads.  No love with adding in the full package name.  No red (errors) in logcat.  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"  
   `<activity android:name="MyListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/man_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.gnub.NewActivity" />
 </application>`

Comment: apologies for the code in the above comment ... haven't figured out the comment formatting yet.

Comment: `MyListActivity` should read `.MyListActivity` but that shouldn't affect `NewActivity`. Can you verify that `NewActivity` is indeed in the package `com.gnub` (the declaration should read `package com.gnub`, not a sub package)

Comment: the package of `NewActivity` is indeed correct.  I corrected `MyListActivity` to `.MyListActivity`

I can launch a new activity from `MyListActivity` with no problem, as long as it is not from within the inner class `MyContentObserver`

Comment: Perhaps startActivity needs to be run from the main UI thread?

Comment: this thread leads me to believe it does not need to be run from the main thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295847/is-it-safe-to-launch-and-activity-from-a-non-ui-thread

Comment: Well, if the code in `onChange` is run you should see a logcat message either way, either it will say that it's launching the activity or that it failed to do so. Are you sure that code is run?

Comment: Yeah, the code runs, it just doesn't launch the intent.  I have even put a method into `MyListActivity` that launches the intent, then called that method from `MyContentObserver`.  I can see the output to logcat, and no signs of failure other than the fact that the new intent never shows up.  

Is it possible that my intent is being covered up by the default calllog? As in my intent displays, and before I can see it, the call log displays?  

Does your code work for you?

Comment: And yeah, I created a new project with your code and had the same result - I see the output to logcat from `MyContentObserver.onChage()` , but the intent never launches.  I never see anything from `NewActivity.onCreate()`

Comment: Just to reiterate: if I put  `startActivity(new Intent(MyListActivity.this, NewActivity.class));` as the last line in `MyListActivity.onCreate()` , `NewActivity` launches fine.