# Launching Android ListActivities

Tags: android, android-listview

I've been looking at the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Everything works fine if I have a simple project that simply shows the layout corresponding to the ListView. However, I'm not able to launch the List activity from a widget button (i.e., a button that exists on a desktop widget).

I'd like to extend this activity to a custom parent activity (that extends activity). The button on the desktop widget has no problems launching my custom parent activity. I'd like to know how I can modify the code tutorial code (given below) so that I can extend my custom activity but still maintain the ListView. This may be a basic java question but I'm no java expert. Thanks.

```
   private void launchButtonActivity(Context context){
        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(context, MyListActivity.class);
        messageIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_GROUP);
        PendingIntent messagePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, messageIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, messagePendingIntent);
    }
```

---

```
package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added the ListActivity to the manifest file as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217475/startactivity-not-working-from-inner-class-that-extends-listactivity. I also confirmed the tutorial worked before trying to instantiate it from another class.

Comment: Okay, after cleaning and refreshing my project, this now works. I've given credit to the earlier question posted on stack overflow as this is the only update that would have fixed the issue.