# got NetworkOnMainThreadExeption in a separate Thread

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect android app with Twitter and I don't know what's wrong with this part of my code :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();
                try {
                    // Error is here
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL); 
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL())));
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

    thread.run();
```

why I got NetworkOnMainThreadException despite using a new Thread ? 
thank you for help..

Comment: Use AsyncTask, please.

Answer (score 9):

Call [`thread.start()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) instead of `thread.run()`; the `run()` method does not spawn a new thread.

Comment: if I use start() instead of run() , I got other exception : CalledFromWrongThreadException.

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: put you `try-catch` block inside the `runOnUIThread`. You can't start an Activity or modify the UI in another thread rather than UI thread itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kai Hmmm.. I thought of that, too. However, `startActivity` is thread-safe according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295847/is-it-safe-to-launch-and-activity-from-a-non-ui-thread