# Resume animation before start another Activity

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation

I have sequence animation. Animation direction is 420mm.When animation finished I try to start another activity with ActivityOptionsCompat (bottom to top animation).Here is a my code

```
private void startSceneAnimation() {
    if (imageView != null) {
        ((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground()).start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginTestActivity.this,
                    SPLoginActivity.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginTestActivity.this,
                            logo,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(logo));
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }, 420);
    }
}
```

Everything working perfect ,but I have one question.Is a any way to starting new activity when animation still finished(without stop animation).I try to start new activity after 300 mm but my sequence animation finished

Answer (score 1):

The `AnimationDrawable` is executed on the UI Thread. An anonymous `Handler` instance generated with no parameters passed in for the `Looper` also runs on the UI Thread. Hence, queuing the activity to change on the `Handler` after any amount of time may not occur until after the `AnimationDrawable` has executed finish, because they are both on the same `Thread`

Try using a `Timer` instead?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
  public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginTestActivity.this,
                SPLoginActivity.class);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginTestActivity.this,
                        logo,
                        ViewCompat.getTransitionName(logo));
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
  }
}, 300);
```

[`Timer` runs in a background thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), and since it exits quickly it shouldn't cause any memory leaks AFAIK.

EDIT: It appears that starting an Activity is done [internally](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) (line 4614) in the Android framework and can be [wonky if attempted from outside the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295847/is-it-safe-to-launch-and-activity-from-a-non-ui-thread). You could try to post the new Intent at the front of the UI Thread Message Queue and see if that works, but it will probably cause the animation to "stop" anyway because that same UI Thread is now being used to handle the activity launch.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
      public void run() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtFrontOfQueue(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginTestActivity.this,
                    SPLoginActivity.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginTestActivity.this,
                            logo,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(logo));
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
          });
      }
    }, 300);
```

Comment: I tried but App crashing. Here is a log result :   Can't create handler inside thread Thread @Mercato

Comment: do you have a more detailed crash log? which line is it referring

Comment: Here is it .      java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Timer-0,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: In this line  ViewCompat.getTransitionName @ Mercato

Comment: You are right ,but animation stoping ,unfortunately @Mercato

Comment: Yes but I have this exception :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread @Mercato

Comment: oops. sorry missed out on the Looper part as it's in another Thread.